# How to create train dataset and test dataset separately in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a fixed training dataset file `train.csv` and another test dataset file `test.csv`. I know `train_test_split()` method in sklearn can do split work. But I want to create 2 datasets seperately with each dataset from exactly each file.

I have tested

```
# The X,Y and X_, Y_ following are training and test samples/labels (dataframes)
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size = 0)
trainX_, testX_, trainY_, testY_ = train_test_split( X_, Y_, test_size = 1.0)  
                                 # not accepted parameter
# ...
dtree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="gini")
dtree.fit(trainX, trainY)
...
Y_pred = dtree.predict(testX_)
```

and take `trainX, trainY` to train, take `testX_, testY_` to predict.
 However, `train_test_split()` method doesn't accept `test_size=1.0`, leading to a failure.

So what's the right way to create training and test datasets separately?

Comment: Given a test size of 1, you are trying to say all of the data should be in the test set, and none in the train set. This defeats the purpose of the train_test_split. If you want a hold-out testing set, you can take some data out before you do the split with [df.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

Comment: What is the purpose of having both `X, y` and `X_, y_`?

Comment: @G.Anderson I just want to create training and test datasets from two files seperately. To achieve that, I tried to use `train_test_split()` twice with test_size = 0 and test_size = 1.0. I think the correct way to do this may have no relation with `train_test_split()` though... Just show my work.

Comment: The purpose of `train_test_split` is to create both a train and a test set with random sampling. If you want to use all of `X_, y_` as a holdout set to test on, then you don't need to split it at all and rather just split `X,y`. If you already have 2 files, then you can just use `dtree.fit(X, y)` and `dtree.score(X_, y_)`, assuming you're happy with both sets being accurate and random samples of the data

Comment: @G.Anderson I have also tried what you suggested. And it seems I must do some encoding stuff to use categorical fields to fit in the decision tree model. Am I right on that?

Comment: Correct, sklearn packages take numerical data and can't handle categorical/string data. `OneHotEncoder` can help in-place. Just make sure you capture all of the categorical levels in both your train and test sets

Comment: @G.Anderson OK I now have ideas to continue my task. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Since it resolved your question, I added my previous comment as an answer. Feel free to accept.And good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of train_test_split is to create both a train and a test set with random sampling. If you want to use all of `X_, y_` as a holdout set to test on, then you don't need to split it at all and rather just split `X, y`. If you already have 2 files, then you can just use `dtree.fit(X, y)` and `dtree.score(X_, y_)`, assuming you're happy with both sets being accurate and random samples of the data